# Index with counta and if?

Tags: excel

Another refresher for me with excel and index function. I am trying to pull the most recent data entry for a given construction task daily progress report. I have a calendar log for daily production on one sheet and am trying to populate "todays" data on the dashboard report that will always pull the last data entered for a given column. I need data from my "actual installed today" column to populate on the Daily Report sheet in the column labeled the same. But I am having problems with the index and counta/countif functions.

[image: [Dashboard Daily Report]

[image: Source Data Daily]

This is the current formula I have been trying to get to work and other variations I have tried.

```
=INDEX(E28:PX28,1,COUNTIF(E24:PX24, "Actual Installed For Today"))
```

Comment: I am needing my dashboard formula to be able to pull the most recent data for whatever the day is. If I enter data on 4/29 I would like the amount installed to display on the dashboard, The next day 4/30 when I enter data in the corresponding column I need it to update again. Continuously updating the dashboard for which ever cell is the most recent with numbers in it.

Comment: Anyone have any idea?